# How Can I Optimize this JAVA code in tems of Speed?

Tags: java, numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem1 {
    static int T,ans[];
    static long A,B;
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        T=scan.nextInt();
        ans=new int[T];
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            A=scan.nextLong();
            B=scan.nextLong();
            for(long j=A;j<=B;j++){
                if(getLucky(j)){
                    ans[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            System.out.println(ans[i]);
        }
    }
    public static boolean getLucky(long j){
        boolean lucky=false;
        long rem,sum=0,sum1=0;
        while(j>0){
            rem=j%10;
            sum=sum+rem;
            sum1=sum1+(rem*rem);
            j=j/10;
        }
        if(isPrime(sum)&&isPrime(sum1)){
            lucky=true;
        }
        return lucky;
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(long sum){
        boolean status=true;
        if(sum!=1){
            for (int i=2; i < sum ;i++ ){
              int n = (int) (sum % i);
              if (n==0){
                    status=false;
                    break;
              }
            }
        }else{
            status=false;
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

This code is for the problem in which i'm finding a total numbers between A and B, whose sum of digits and sum of square of digits are prime. But I need to make it Optimal. How Can i do so?

Comment: The first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842418/prime-numbers-code-help) will give you a much better way to determine if a number is prime or not. You might also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969330/printing-out-prime-numbers-from-array).

Comment: You should ask a specific question. If you want your code reviewed - you should try at [stackexchange code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Code optimization can be tricky.
Make the code optimal can be something different.

There's a lot of sub-question:
Optimization, in term of speed / memory ?
On which device?
From a fresh start, or after a long running time ?

But first, give variable a explicit name, because A,B,T  means nothing to me/ others code, and longer variable name won't slow down your code.
Second, use a profiler may help you, I usually use jvisualvm.exe (in the jdk).
Third, a faster code on your machine won't necessary be faster on a other computer / device.

In your getLucky method,  the lucky variable is not necessary, you could do:
    return (isPrime(sum)&&isPrime(sum1));

but it will render your code less readable.

In your isPrime method, the for loop check the i is a integer and the sum is a long. So if the sum is bigger than MAX_INTEGER you will be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking more numbers than you need in isPrime.  You only need to check up to sqrt(sum) since if sum is factorable, it must have at least one factor <= its square root.

```
public static boolean isPrime(long sum){
    boolean status=true;
    if(sum!=1){
        int limit = Math.sqrt(sum);
        for (int i=2; i <= limit;i++ ){
          int n = (int) (sum % i);
          if (n==0){
                return false;

          }
        }
    }else{
        status=false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

There are a few other little things I see too.  Like you keep setting booleans and then returning them.  Once you know the number isn't prime just return right away.  There's no need to set status, break out of the loop and then return.  Ditto for getLucky().  Instead of 
`if(isPrime(sum)&&isPrime(sum1)){
            lucky=true;
        }`

use `return isPrime(sum) && isPrime(sum1);`