# How to get number of prime integers from an array of size 40?

Tags: java, arrays, primes

I am trying to write a simple program that gives out the maximum, minimum, number of even integers, number of odd integers and number of prime integers from an array size of 40.

I write the following code:

```
package TESTING;
import java.util.*;

public class testClass{  
    public static void main (String args[]){

    int numbers[]= {1,5,-9,12,-3,89,18,23,4,-6,14,-5,87,17,47,-73,39,49,56,71,
                    3,0,-2,23,-8,45,63,71,5,29,-4,15,78,37,99,-66,44,94,65,73};  
    //Find minimum (lowest) value in array using loop  
    System.out.println("Minimum Value = " + getMinValue(numbers));  
    //Find maximum (largest) value in array using loop  
    System.out.println("Maximum Value = " + getMaxValue(numbers));  
    System.out.println("Even Numbers = " + even(numbers));
    System.out.println("Odd Numbers = " + odd(numbers));
    for(int number = 1; number<=numbers.length; number++){
    //print prime numbers only
    if(isPrime(numbers)){

       System.out.println("+ numbers");
    }
  }


//Find maximum (largest) value in array using loop  
public static int getMaxValue(int[] numbers){  
int maxValue = numbers[0];  
for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){  
    if(numbers[i] > maxValue){  
        maxValue = numbers[i];  
    }  
}  
return maxValue;  
}  

 //Find minimum (lowest) value in array using loop  
 public static int getMinValue(int[] numbers){  
int minValue = numbers[0];  
for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){  
    if(numbers[i] < minValue){  
        minValue = numbers[i];  
    }  
}  
return minValue;  
}  
//Find even numbers in array 
public static int even(int[] numbers)
{
int countLength = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        countLength++; 
    }
}

return countLength; 
}

public static int odd(int[] numbers)
{
int countOdd =0;
for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] %2 != 0){
        countOdd++;
    }
}
return countOdd;

}

public static boolean isPrime(int numbers[]){
     for(int i=2; i<numbers.length; i++){
   if(numbers.length%i == 0){
       return false; //number is divisible so its not prime
        }
     }
     return true; //number is prime now
 }    


}
```

I couldn't get where is the problem? It is not showing the prime numbers in the output.
I get the following output:

**Output**

```
Minimum Value = -73
Maximum Value = 99
Even Numbers = 14
Odd Numbers = 26
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: And the output is? What error are you getting?

Comment: in your isPrime method, I believe your intention was to do a mod with the contents of the int[] and not the length of the array?

Comment: How about some properly indented code as well?

Comment: Your isPrime is wrongly implemented. See a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969330/printing-out-prime-numbers-from-array?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the problem. Observe the code changes properly:-

```
for (int number = 0; number < numbers.length; number++) {
            // print prime numbers only
            if (isPrime(numbers[number])) {
                System.out.println("Prime= "+numbers[number]);
            }
        }
```

`isPrime(number)` should be used and not `numbers[]` and then your `isPrime()` method should be

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false; // number is divisible so its not prime
            }
        }
        return true; // number is prime now
    }
```

Make these code changes. It'll work.

Comment: Fixed some logic in there for ya :D

Comment: changed both? the `for` and the `isPrime()`? If so, it must work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print prime numbers..yes? Then remove double quotes as I edited below.

Try this: inside for loop when you trying to print prime numbers.

```
if(isPrime(numbers[i])){

   System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

Instead of

```
if(isPrime(numbers)){

   System.out.println("+ numbers");
}
```

And edit you isPrime function too.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int numbers){
    for(int i=2; i<numbers; i++){
        if(numbers%i == 0){
            return false; //number is divisible so its not prime
        }
    }
     return true; //number is prime now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a java `List` from the data with `Arrays.asList()`

Sort the list. Your first and last elements are now the minimum and max.

Use [CollectionUtils.countMatches()](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#countMatches%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) and write a Predicate to test if the numer isPrime, isEven, isOdd...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better variant for isPrime:

```
public static int[] getPrime(int[] someNumbers) {
  int[] temp = new int[someNumbers.length];
  int cnt = 0;
  for (int num : someNumbers) {
    int max = num / 2;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        temp[cnt++] = num;
      }
    }
  }
  int[] result = new int[cnt];
  System.arrayCopy(temp, 0, result, 0, cnt);
  return result;
}
```

Note: to print it you must iterate over result of the method and print each number

```
public static void printArray(int[] anArray) {
  boolean firstRun = true;
  for (int num : anArray) {
    if (! firstRun) {
      System.out.print(", ");
    } else {
      firstRun = false;
    }     
    System.out.print("" + num);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```